# HSEARCH 700061: Index a list of enums with Hibernate Search 6

Tags: enums, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I am new in Hibernate search 6 world, I want to index a list of enum in my entity, but I get unfortunatly this Error

> HSEARCH700061: Unable to index-embed type 'com.commons.enums.B

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<B> b;
}

public enum B {
TEST1,
TEST2,
TEST3
}
```

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@IndexedEmbedded` does not make sense in your case, since it's supposed to embed fields from the target type, and your enum type does not define fields itself (e.g. via `@FullTextField` on its properties).

What you want is simply to define a field in your entity `A`:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {
    @KeywordField // Replace @IndexedEmbedded with this
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<B> b;
}

public enum B {
TEST1,
TEST2,
TEST3
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, why can I not use @GenericField because it is an Enum ?

Comment: You can use `@GenericField` as well. In this case, they are equivalent. [`@KeywordField`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-annotations-keywordfield) just offers more options, such as support for normalizers, but here I didn't use any of them, so it's the same as `@GenericField`.

Comment: @tissa Please make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {
    @GenericField
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<B> b;
}

public enum B {
TEST1,
TEST2,
TEST3
}
```

b.should(f.match().field("b").matching(B.valueOf(keyWord)));